# Webpack loader exclude specific files extensions

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have files that include the string "theme". For example:

- `button.theme.scss`

What I want is a way to create two rules, one for files with `/theme.scss/` and one for the rest.

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'postcss-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\theme.scss$/,
        use: [
          ...
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The first rule should **exclude** the `theme.scss` Files. I tried to use `exclude`, but it works only for directories.